# Does DynDNS always point to my external IP?

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, ip-address, dynamic-dns

I want to be able to `ssh` to my box from anywhere on Internet so I am doing `port-forwarding`. I've registered with free `dyndns.org` account so that evenif my `external ip` changes, it doesn't affect the service.

I just want to clear one doubt that I have:

At any point in time, the `url` provided by dyndns.org should point to my external IP address (the one that I get form whatismyip.com), correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The URL provided by DynDNS should always point to your external IP address, however you need to make sure that DynDNS updates your record if your IP address changes. For some ISPs, this isn't necessary, while for others your IP could change on a daily basis.

To do that, there are two possibilities:

- Your router is DynDNS-capable and will allow you to enter your DynDNS credentials. It will take care of the update process.
- You can [download an updater](http://dyn.com/support/clients/) for your system.

  > Using an update client with your DynDNS or Dyn Standard DNS hostname allows you to make sure you can always reach your home network, because it makes sure that your hostname is always up-to-date with the latest IP address. The update client runs in the background, so once you have it properly configured you don’t have to worry about it; you only need to remember your hostname to reach your files and services.

Comment: thanks. I have DynDNS-capable router and I did set up that section of router configuration. I am struggling with http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20086/how-to-debug-ssh-port-forwarding --- if this one belongs to here, please migrate :) thanks.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, your question would be equally fine for Super User and Unix.SE. If you already have it at Unix.SE, there's no need to migrate it over!

Comment: Yes, somehow now it feels on this site, it has more chances of getting right treatment. Anyways, thanks for response.